# Form generated using jsonschema causing vertical navbar's (created using crema) contents to shift left (React)

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, styles, jsonschema

I have a vertical sidebar that I used from the "components" folder in "AppLayout" folder of crema and I have made a tree structure of contents/names there which renders properly in general. But when I add the form created using jsonschema, the contents in the vertical sidebar moves to the left. I have tried changing the styling in the  component which I believe is causing the issue to no avail. Could someone suggest where I could be going wrong.

Comment: I'm afraid you're going to have to provide some code to create a minimal reproduceable example here https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example =]